# In $C_{\infty}$ , does function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ have removable singularity at $z=\infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

In $C_{\infty}$ , does function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ have removable singularity at $z=\infty$ ? Because $f(\frac{1}{w}) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{w}}$ , $\frac{1}{w}$ isn't define at w = 0 and $lim_{w\to0}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{w}} = 0$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does function f(z)=1/z have removable singularity at z=∞?

Comment: Yes, and you seem to have a proof already.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is correct in C∞.

Answer (score 1):

Often, when we define arithmetic on $C_\infty$, we actually define division by $\infty$ (except for $\infty/\infty$), so $f$ is actually *defined and continuous* at $\infty$.

If you only define $f$ on the finite complex numbers, then you are correct, $f$ would have a removable singularity at $\infty$.